# Opened programs in Unity

Tags: unity

I noticed a problem on Unity. So, when I open, for example, program Eclipse which is IDE for programming languages as Java and PHP it doesn't showed as opened in Unity box, so if I minimize this program I can't open it again, because when I pres on Eclipse icon in Unity box it starts Eclipse again not open previous minimized program. How to fix this, because otherwise I have to use basic Ubuntu layout to use some programs?

Comment: You should [report this as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+filebug).

Comment: Can't you just Alt+Tab into the minimized Eclipse as a transitional solution untill the bug is fixed?

Comment: There is already a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/748516

Comment: This bug you are experiencing has already been documented as a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/748516). If you have queries, please post comments in the bug report. I am now proceeding to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Super-W (Spread mode), to zoom out on all windows in all workspaces.